# DRF - html post options only for user logged in

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have the following serializer:

```
class WidgetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())

    class Meta:
        model=Widget
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'description', 'username', 'code', 'owner', 'list')
```

The problem is that the 'list' field, which is a drop down, gives all lists whereas I only want it to display lists that are owned by the user currently logged in.

Here's the respective models:

```
class WidgetList(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('MyUser')
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', db_index=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class MPTTMEta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']

class Widget(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('MyUser', related_name='MyUser_owner')
    list = models.ForeignKey('WidgetList')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to limit it through a SlugRelatedField as per the documentation here -

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield

I then used it like so -

```
list = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
    queryset=WidgetList.objects.filter(owner=3),
    many=True,
    slug_field='name'
 )
```

All I need to figure out now is to pass the serializers.CurrentUserDefault() in the filter for the queryset, or pass request.user.

Answer (score 1):

I am a beginner in django. I hope that I could help.

Just try this
`WidgetList.objects.filter(owner=request.user)`